# Save Placeholder on Postback

Tags: asp.net, session, postback, viewstate, placeholder

I am creating a table dynamically on an click event of a Button

```
private void CreateDynamicTable()
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();

        int tblRows = Rows;
        int tblCols = Columns;

        Table tbl = new Table();
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .        
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);

        ViewState["dynamictable"] = true;
    }
```

Now in an another Event, i find this table in the `PlaceHolder1` but it says no table found in `PlaceHolder1`.

How to save `PlaceHolder1` state on so that all controls stay saved in `PlaceHolder1`

I am also using this to save the table in `View State`

```
 protected override void LoadViewState(object earlierState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(earlierState);
        if (ViewState["dynamictable"] == null)
            CreateDynamicTable();
    }
```

Please help me to solve this problem.